# Proof by strong induction combinatorics problem: $1(1!) + 2(2!) + 3(3!) + \dots + n(n!) = (n+1)! - 1$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction, factorial

$1(1!) + 2(2!) + 3(3!) + \dots + n(n!) = (n+1)! - 1$

How do we prove this by strong induction?

I know how to do it with weak induction, but how would strong induction work with this problem?

Comment: Weak induction is merely a special case of strong induction. If you’ve proved it by weak induction, you have automatically proved it by strong induction as well.

Comment: The difference between weak and strong induction is in the inductive hypothesis.  You assume more with strong induction (assume that the claim is true for $n=1..k$ instead of just assuming that the claim is true for $n=k$).  The two inductions, however, give equivalent theories.

Comment: There are several post about the same sum:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301615/prove-by-mathematical-induction-11-22-cdot-cdot-cdot-nn-n
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326105/sum-i-1n-i-cdot-i-n1-1-by-induction
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917367/using-induction-to-prove-that-sum-r-1n-r-cdot-r-n1-1
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948757/prove-11-dotsnn-n1-1-using-induction
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455778/prove-sum-i-1n-i-cdot-i-n1-1

Answer (score 1):

The induction step  $$(n+1)(n+1)!+(n+1)!=(n+2)!$$